# Firebase google-service.json File Link Not Working

Tags: android, firebase

I'm in the process of creating an application using firebase backend and the link for google-service.json file is not working. Is this happening to anyone. I can't download the file. I go to my project settings and try to download the file from there, but the link doesn't work. I try opening the link on a separate tab and it doesn't work. I think is an invalid link. I'm using chrome as the browser. I saw a post on stackoverflow about this and the solution was to go to project settings and try downloading file from there. Is there any other solution. has anyone experience this? thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bug reports for problems with the Firebase console should be directed to Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: why? there's another question similar to this one... no one took that one down

Comment: Please do contact Firebase support in case there is a problem with the service, or a problem with your project.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and no one here can fix your project or the service if it's broken.